# mysql update from another table error column cannot be null

Tags: mysql, join, crud

I have these table structure:

```
point
===============================================
column  | type | comment
===============================================
id      | int  | primary key (auto increment)
type    | enum | 'paradise', 'culinary'
post_id | int  | foreign key to culinary.id
user_id | int  |
===============================================

culinary
===============================================
column  | type         | comment
===============================================
id      | int          | primary key (auto inc)
title   | varchar(255) | 
user_id | int          |
===============================================
```

I want to update the `point.user_id` field using the values from `culinary.user_id`. but I got an error message saying `column 'user_id' cannot be null` even though when I select each tables, there are no records that has a null user_id...

here's what I tried:

```
-- first attempt gets error message > 1048 - Column 'user_id' cannot be null
update `point`
set `user_id` = (
  select `culinary`.`user_id`
  from `culinary`
  where `culinary`.`id` = `point`.`post_id`
  and `point`.`type` = 'culinary'
)

-- second attempt but still the same error message
update `point`
set `user_id` = (
  select `culinary`.`user_id`
  from `culinary`
  where `culinary`.`id` = `point`.`post_id`
)
where `type` = 'culinary'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join:

```
update `point` p
inner join `culinary` c on c.`id` = p.`post_id`
set p.`user_id` = c.`user_id`
where p.`type` = 'culinary'
```